# How to add a column to a table from within lightswitch

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a SQL Server Database and it is a requirement for my lightswitch app that the administrator be able to add new columns to certain tables. Is that even possible? The only way I could think to do it is to write an "ALTER" stored procedure in the database and call it from lightswitch, but that seems a little messy. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you'll be able to find a way to **physically** add a new column to a table after an application has been published, LightSwitch is not going to like it. You may even find that the application refuses to run.

For an *attached database*, the **model** that LightSwitch creates for it can only be updated by running the *Update Data Source* command, which can only be done by the developer at **design-time**. And if the database in the *intrinsic* database, it also can only be changed at design-time.

So the short answer to "*Is that even possible?*" is "no".

Comment: I kept running into that problem when the data model was modified and the application would thrown an exception if the source wasn't updated. Side question: is there a reason why Lightswitch stores all the screen configurations in one(or three) .isml file/s?

Comment: That's actually changed in the new version of LightSwitch that's in the VS 2013 Preview. Each table, screen etc has been broken out into it's own lsml file. This is primarily to improve scenarios where more than one developer is working on the same LightSwitch application, or where the application is under source control.

Answer (score 0):

An `ALTER` stored procedure would probably be the best way to achieve what you are talking about, but I wouldn't recommend it.

How are you then going to store and retrieve data from these columns?  What happens when you start to get column name collisions between tables?

It might be better if you give us a higher level description of what you are trying to achieve, but taking a guess I would suggest you look at the entity-attribute-value pattern for storing arbitrary user data.

Comment: Im looking for some functionality already existing in lightswitch. To me the stored procedure is a solution but is not quite the right one.. We have additional properties for just about everything, but thats not what im looking for either..